# How to transfer links between two pages in multi-page backbone application?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I searched for creating Multi-page(physical pages like index.jsp, page1.jsp, page2.jsp and so on) but i didn't found anything useful. so i started out by trying to implement on my own.

i created separate jsp/html files in the following names index.jsp(contains dashboard page), customer, page2 and so on. I created seprate router for each page to route various views inside that single page.

i have created a top menu bar like the following.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='index.jsp' class="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="customer.jsp">customer</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.jsp">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.jsp">Page3</a></li>
<ul>
```

the pages loads fine when i click those "li" and i have two buttons to list customers and create new customer in the customer page, on clicking that buttons i route to customer/list(customer.jsp#customer/list) and customer/new(customer.jsp#customer/new) in Router and load respective views. There is no trouble so far and i thought creating Multi-page backbone app was easy.

I get into trouble when i add sub menus in the top menu bar like the following.

```
<ol class="nav">
    <li><a href='index.jsp' class="dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
         <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="customer.jsp">Customer</a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="customer.jsp#/customer/list"> Customer List</a></li>
             <li><a href="customer.jsp#/customer/new"> New Customer</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="page2.jsp">Page2</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.jsp">Page3</a></li>
<ol>
```

Trouble for me:

When i click on Customer List from index.jsp it redirects to that url perfectly and loads the content, and when i click Customer New from Customer List page, the url gets changed but the content gets changed only when i click refresh button in my browser.

Same is the case when i click on Customer New first and then click on Customer List page. In other words, the first url redirect works and the following url redirects works only on the click of refresh button.

Since i'm new to this world of backbone, i couldn't figure it out on my own. i'm posting this after a day of Googling. Can someone help me out to fix this issue.

**REASON TO MOVE ON MULIT-PAGE(PHYSICAL)**

1) To avoid loading of view js files which are not need for the particular page.(Eg. Dashboard loads all the view js which are needed for customer page,page1 and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Your JS files get cached by the browser, so using multiple pages solely to avoid loading them all it once isn't a great idea. Instead, you should be minifying and gzipping the your js files all into one single js file that is included on every page.

A good java minifier if you are using maven is https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin

As to why the your content is changing, I need to see your js

Comment: But my requirement is to develop multi-pages application using backbone.